# How to show previous url after user has canceled dialog with message from Activity#mayStop()?

Tags: gwt, gwt-places, gwt-activities

In our app we need to check if the data is saved when we are in a particular place before navigating away from it. So the user should be able to negate a browser back button request. But by the time that the history value change event is received the url has already been changed. The History class doesn't seem to have a way to restore the url back. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In GWT 2.1 you get Activities and Places. And activity has a [maystop](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/Activity.html#mayStop%28%29) method, which is exactly what you want, if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `window.onunload` or `window.onbeforeunload` javascript callback to confrim/save state.
[onbeforeunload example](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately we're not actually changing pages, just displaying different parts of the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually implemented this behavior yet, but here is my plan and maybe it will work for you.

1) Each time you receive an onHistoryChanged event and decide to allow it, save the current historyToken in an instance variable somewhere.

2) Keep track of activity on the page that should block navigation. Use a data structure that can keep track of multiple activities, like multiple file uploads, multiple edits, etc.

3) When you receive a new onHistoryChanged event, if your data structure from #2 indicates that it's not safe to navigate, avoid changing the page and restore the historyToken that you saved in #1. I'm assuming that you can do this either by:

a) Calling History.newItem(oldHistoryToken, false) or

b) Calling History.newItem(oldHistoryToken, true) and keeping a flag to force the next onHistoryChanged to be ignored.

Again, I haven't actually implemented this so let me know how it works out.

If you have links that allow the user to leave the app and you want to prevent that as well, you'll need to also add an onbeforeunload.

Comment: I've implemented something of the sort. I originally thought that I'd end up with duplicate tokens on the history stack, but apparently the History code is smart enough not to do that.

Comment: What I actually do is I'm keeping track of the current URL (actually just the history token) when I do a History.newItem, I've got a wrapper class that does that. When the user cancels the navigation event, I just add call History.newItem (with the false parm) with the last saved token.  So problem solved, thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`PlaceManagerImpl`](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/source/browse/gwtp-core/gwtp-mvp-client/src/main/java/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/PlaceManagerImpl.java) class from the [gwt-platform](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgwt-platform%2F&rct=j&q=gwtp&ei=N_jcTPreD4PJhAfR8oyYDQ&usg=AFQjCNH9fp0Iq8wytWg6wOo3LQZGxqX2Rw&sig2=cxxRVBgA011llpc1G2Hj7Q&cad=rja) framework. Especially the `onValueChange()` method and the methods dealing with the `onLeaveQuestion` field.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Basically that's what I ended up doing. Thanks for the link to source code browser, I'm always forgetting that it's available.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6726) issue report, t.broyer explains in his [comment](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6726#c5) that such behavior was planned during design of Places framework. The most important part is:

> mayStop was a mistake, or it should have only been called when unloading the app, not for internal navigation within the app.

So probably it's better to not use it at all...